# Update Test fails: "Expected response to be a <3XX: redirect>, but was a <204: No Content>"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, testing

I wanted to run this test, but it gives me an error an I don't understand why since hours.

Here is the complete error:

```
 FAIL["test_should_update_preference", Minitest::Result, 2.7792289879871532]
 test_should_update_preference#Minitest::Result (2.78s)
        Expected response to be a <3XX: redirect>, but was a <204: No Content>
        Response body: 
        test/controllers/preferences_controller_test.rb:20:in `block in <class:PreferencesControllerTest>'
```

Thanks to everyone who looks at my problem!

This is the test:
      test "should update preference" do
        patch preference_url(@preference), params: { preference: { accepted: @preference.accepted, institute_id: @preference.institute_id, preference_value: @preference.preference_value, user_id: @preference.user_id, wei_preference_value: @preference.wei_preference_value } }
        assert_redirected_to preferences_path
      end

Here is the Controller:

```
 class PreferencesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_preference, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /preferences
  # GET /preferences.json
  def index
    @preferences = Preference.all
  end

  # GET /preferences/1
  # GET /preferences/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /preferences/new
  def new
    @preference = Preference.new
  end

  # GET /preferences/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /preferences
  # POST /preferences.json
  def create
    @preference = Preference.new(preference_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @preference.save
        format.html { redirect_to preferences_path}
      else
        format.html { render :index }
        format.json { render json: @preference.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def create_all
    @institutes = Institute.all
    @institutes.each do |li|
        @preference = Preference.create(institute_id: li.id, user_id: current_user.id, preference_value: 5)
    end
    lash[:success] = "Sie können die Präferenzen jetzt bearbeiten."
    render :index
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /preferences/1
  # PATCH/PUT /preferences/1.json
  def update
    if @preference.update_attributes(preference_params)
      flash[:success] = "Die Präferenz wurde aktualisiert."
      redirect_to preferences_path
    end
  end

  # DELETE /preferences/1
  # DELETE /preferences/1.json
  def destroy
    @preference.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to preferences_url }
    end
  end
```

And this is the log-file, which I get, when I perform the Update task in my brwoser:

```
Started PATCH "/preferences/43" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-03-02 15:36:06 +0100
Processing by PreferencesController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"CXcMiSLQdlUeJf75g/uClWaI89f/nxypzb60yphXh26sJx5E0bUu39SAEckE13GeozuCN9WQ3eBUTbPz1/WqoQ==", "preference"=>{"user_id"=>"2", "institute_id"=>"1", "preference_value"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Speichern", "id"=>"43"}
  [1m[36mPreference Load (0.3ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "preferences".* FROM "preferences" WHERE "preferences"."id" = ? LIMIT ?[0m  [["id", 43], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  [1m[35m (0.2ms)[0m  [1m[36mbegin transaction[0m
  [1m[36mInstitute Load (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "institutes".* FROM "institutes" WHERE "institutes"."id" = ? LIMIT ?[0m  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  [1m[36mUser Load (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?[0m  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  [1m[35mSQL (31.4ms)[0m  [1m[33mUPDATE "preferences" SET "preference_value" = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE "preferences"."id" = ?[0m  [["preference_value", 1], ["updated_at", "2018-03-02 14:36:06.852000"], ["id", 43]]
  [1m[35m (23.5ms)[0m  [1m[36mcommit transaction[0m
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/preferences
Completed 302 Found in 76ms (ActiveRecord: 55.6ms)


Started GET "/preferences" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-03-02 15:36:06 +0100
Processing by PreferencesController#index as HTML
  Rendering preferences/index.html.erb within layouts/application
  [1m[36mUser Load (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?[0m  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  [1m[36mPreference Exists (0.2ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  1 AS one FROM "preferences" WHERE "preferences"."user_id" = ? LIMIT ?[0m  [["user_id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  [1m[36mPreference Load (0.4ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT "preferences".* FROM "preferences" WHERE "preferences"."user_id" = ?[0m  [["user_id", 2]]
  [1m[36mInstitute Load (0.3ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "institutes".* FROM "institutes" WHERE "institutes"."id" = ? LIMIT ?[0m  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  [1m[36mInstitute Load (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "institutes".* FROM "institutes" WHERE "institutes"."id" = ? LIMIT ?[0m  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  [1m[36mInstitute Load (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "institutes".* FROM "institutes" WHERE "institutes"."id" = ? LIMIT ?[0m  [["id", 3], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  [1m[36mInstitute Load (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "institutes".* FROM "institutes" WHERE "institutes"."id" = ? LIMIT ?[0m  [["id", 4], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  [1m[36mInstitute Load (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "institutes".* FROM "institutes" WHERE "institutes"."id" = ? LIMIT ?[0m  [["id", 5], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  [1m[36mInstitute Load (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "institutes".* FROM "institutes" WHERE "institutes"."id" = ? LIMIT ?[0m  [["id", 6], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  [1m[36mInstitute Load (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "institutes".* FROM "institutes" WHERE "institutes"."id" = ? LIMIT ?[0m  [["id", 7], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  [1m[36mInstitute Load (0.4ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "institutes".* FROM "institutes" WHERE "institutes"."id" = ? LIMIT ?[0m  [["id", 8], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  [1m[36mInstitute Load (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "institutes".* FROM "institutes" WHERE "institutes"."id" = ? LIMIT ?[0m  [["id", 9], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  [1m[36mInstitute Load (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "institutes".* FROM "institutes" WHERE "institutes"."id" = ? LIMIT ?[0m  [["id", 10], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  [1m[36mInstitute Load (0.5ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "institutes".* FROM "institutes" WHERE "institutes"."id" = ? LIMIT ?[0m  [["id", 11], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  [1m[36mInstitute Load (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "institutes".* FROM "institutes" WHERE "institutes"."id" = ? LIMIT ?[0m  [["id", 12], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  [1m[36mInstitute Load (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "institutes".* FROM "institutes" WHERE "institutes"."id" = ? LIMIT ?[0m  [["id", 13], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  [1m[36mInstitute Load (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "institutes".* FROM "institutes" WHERE "institutes"."id" = ? LIMIT ?[0m  [["id", 14], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  [1m[36mInstitute Load (0.3ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "institutes".* FROM "institutes" WHERE "institutes"."id" = ? LIMIT ?[0m  [["id", 15], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  [1m[36mInstitute Load (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "institutes".* FROM "institutes" WHERE "institutes"."id" = ? LIMIT ?[0m  [["id", 16], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  [1m[36mInstitute Load (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "institutes".* FROM "institutes" WHERE "institutes"."id" = ? LIMIT ?[0m  [["id", 17], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  [1m[36mInstitute Load (0.2ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "institutes".* FROM "institutes" WHERE "institutes"."id" = ? LIMIT ?[0m  [["id", 18], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  [1m[36mInstitute Load (0.2ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "institutes".* FROM "institutes" WHERE "institutes"."id" = ? LIMIT ?[0m  [["id", 19], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  [1m[36mInstitute Load (0.4ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "institutes".* FROM "institutes" WHERE "institutes"."id" = ? LIMIT ?[0m  [["id", 20], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  [1m[36mInstitute Load (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "institutes".* FROM "institutes" WHERE "institutes"."id" = ? LIMIT ?[0m  [["id", 21], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Rendered preferences/index.html.erb within layouts/application (74.8ms)
  Rendered layouts/_rails_default.html.erb (191.3ms)
  Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (3.5ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (19.9ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (1.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 326ms (Views: 317.8ms | ActiveRecord: 4.4ms)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `update` method if your `update_attributes` method call fails, it doesn't render anything, which is why you're getting the `No Content` error.

First off, you should add an else statement to that method to so that it doesn't come back with no content.  Rendering some sort of error status will do.  Then you should put a debugger and see why it's failing.  You can use the `.errors` method on the instance to see why it's not valid.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the advice! I updated my controller and put an else statement into the controller.

```
def update
    if @preference.update_attributes(preference_params)
      flash[:success] = "Die Präferenz wurde aktualisiert."
      redirect_to preferences_path
    else
      flash[:error] = "Die Präferenz konnte nicht aktualisiert werden."
      redirect_to preference_path
    end
  end
```

now the test would be successful if I put preferences_path into the else action. That's not really the goal of my test so I put institute_path instead of preference_path in the else statement. Now I got the failure:

```
FAIL["test_should_update_preference", Minitest::Result, 1.8134876039985102]
 test_should_update_preference#Minitest::Result (1.82s)
        Expected response to be a redirect to <http://www.example.com/preferences> but was a redirect to <http://www.example.com/institutes>.
        Expected "http://www.example.com/preferences" to be === "http://www.example.com/institutes".
        test/controllers/preferences_controller_test.rb:20:in `block in <class:PreferencesControllerTest>'
```

I will Google the .error method and apply it to report what the mistake was.